# Nested ng-repeat undefined errors in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I'm having an issue with a very simple nested ng-repeat with AngularJS 1.2.0-rc3.

I have a JSON object inside my controller representing a menu structure, like this:

```
$scope.menus = [
  {
    title: "menu1", 
    action: "#", 
    menus: [
      {
        title: "submenu1_1",
        action: "stuff"
      },
      {
        title: "submenu1_2",
        action: "moreStuff"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "menu2", 
    action: "#", 
    menus: [
      {
        title: "submenu2_1",
        action: "awesomeStuff"
      },
      {
        title: "submenu2_2",
        action: "moreAwesomeStuff"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My view uses this information to create a Bootstrap `nav` menu structure, like this:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li ng-repeat="menu in menus" ng-class="{dropdown: menu.menus}">
      <a href="{{menu.action}}" ng-class="{'dropdown-toggle': menu.menus}" data-toggle="dropdown">{{menu.title}}</a>
      <ul ng-if="menu.menus" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="submenu in menu.menus">
          <a href="{{submenu.action}}">{{submenu.title}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This should work fine, and it does... 50% of the time. Sometimes, almost randomly, the menu won't show up at all and I'll get this error in the console:

```
Error: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'node.childNodes')
```

Is there something wrong with my markup? The error appears sometimes on page load, and always when I click on a submenu (in my code the actions are replaced simply by an "#").

Comment: in jsfiddle it is always works: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/HwhCK/

Comment: The controller to which that scope belongs to is part of a module upon which my main app depends. It gets loaded successfully and I can see the $scope.menus object correctly in the console *before* the error shows up. I'm baffled.

Comment: Can you somehow toss together a jsfiddle? Hard to diagnose if it currently works.

Comment: I just managed to find out what the problem was. It had nothing to do with the controller or the markup. I was putting the <div> with the directive inside the ng-view, which resulted in some funky behavior (it was probably getting overwritten by the actual template).
A simple distraction, in the end. This question should be closed!